# Running into Network error: ws://localhost:3000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 Node.JS

Tags: node.js, syntax-error

I am currently trying to set up a Discord / Atshop bot. There is no need for you to know what Atshop.io is for this error - should be very easy to fix I am just not well versed in Node or this error.

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/atomic404/atshop-replacements-discord-bot

I have entered all necessary info into the config file and already debugged and solved several errors like adding client intent etc..

Now when I run "node index.js" I get this error:

```
 throw err;
        ^
Network error: ws://localhost:3000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

And when I run:

```
pm2 start index.js --watch --name "Bot"
```

I get a list that says the bot is online for 0 seconds and then it closes and brings me back to empty terminal line..

In desperate need of help here!

Thanks!